# API call not allowed for non-Compliance Recording call error in MS Graph Communications Client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I have an application where I am able to make a Bot application, Join Ms teams meeting (by providing joinUrl to my endpoint). I am able to achieve this.

But when I try to start recording the meeting using the Bot (by updating recording status of the call using the below mentioned method), i get the following error :

> Code: 8506 Message: API call not allowed for non-Compliance Recording
>   call

I am using Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls v1.2.0.850

To start recording the meeting, I am using the following:

```
await Call.UpdateRecordingStatusAsync(RecordingStatus.Recording).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have followed the instructions for how to setup a PolicyRecordingCompliance mentioned in PolicyRecordingBot Sample https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot

But seems like this Policy is different than the use case which I am trying to achieve.
In the Sample, it requires something as RecordedUser whereas I need my Bot to start recording the meeting as soon as it joins a meeting.